# unknown messagebox in .net framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

In my vb.net windows application i have written some codes inside `MouseMove` event .
when my application runs and the cursor come inside my application one `messagebox` pops up and being invisible within a second . I'm unable to read what is there inside that `messagebox` .

can anyone please help me to get rid of this unnecessary `messagebox` which is having caption .net framework.
Here is my code

```
Public Class ToolDashboard
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Collections.Specialized
    Public Class CompassToolDashboard
    Dim path As NameValueCollection

        Private Sub ToolDashboard_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Me.Location = New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - (Me.Width - 50), Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height)
            path = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ToolPath")
        End Sub

         Private Sub ToolDashboard_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
              Me.BringToFront()
              While Me.Opacity < 1
                 Me.Opacity = Me.Opacity + 0.06
             End While
        End Sub

       Private Sub ToolDashboard_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
             While Me.Opacity > 0
                Me.Opacity = Me.Opacity - 0.001
             End While
       End Sub    
       Private Sub CloseForm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseForm.Click, CloseForm.Click
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()
        End Sub

        Private Sub ShareTool_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles VMDashboard.Click
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path("IndexGenerator")) 
        'getting path for Indexgenerator.exe from app.config                 
        'Index generator.exe is present in a remote system      
        End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?  I'm pretty sure that a `While` loop with `Application.DoEvents` inside an event handler (especially for something like MouseMouve, which is fired **very** often) is not a good idea.

Comment: when cursor is on my application form will be shown (by adding 0.01 to the form opacity ) else form will be invisible (by deducing 0.003 from form opacity) ..please suggest if you have any better idea to accomplish this .

Comment: Are you sure it was a [Message box](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC534155.png) and not a [balloon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511451.aspx) or a [tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511495.aspx)?

Comment: yes it is a MessageBox ..

Comment: Could you post a screen capture of the “MessageBox”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MessageBox` may be due to an exception thrown by `ConfigurationManager.GetSection`. You will have to verify this using breakpoints or configure your IDE to break on exceptions automatically (in Visual Studio 2008: Debug > Exceptions..., place a checkmark next to Common Language Runtime Exceptions).

---

The while loops in your event handlers will not perform a fading animation like you're expecting. You can do this using a `Timer`. Also, I believe the Form will be unable to receive `MouseEnter` events if you set the `Opacity` all the way to 0.0. Here's an example that fades between 0.3 and 1.0:

```
Private WithEvents timer As New Timer()
Private visible As Boolean

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    timer.Interval = 1
    Opacity = 0.3
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    visible = True
    timer.Start()
    MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    visible = False
    timer.Start()
    MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
    If (visible) Then
        If (Opacity < 0.94) Then
            Opacity += 0.06
        Else
            Opacity = 1.0
            timer.Stop()
        End If
    Else
        If (Opacity > 0.31) Then
            Opacity -= 0.01
        Else
            Opacity = 0.3
            timer.Stop()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure about the `messagebox` you are talking about but the method `ToolDashboard_MouseMove` should not have this while loop inside because it makes your application stuck as soon as it triggered the first time so it will never leaves and never continue with the application. instead you should use [mouse enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and [mouse leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave.aspx) events on the specific control you want, and if you don't have a control there you should create a [panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) or something similar, which will not be seen by the user, but you'll be able to use the events.

Comment: ok.. I have done as you said . But still getting the same MessageBox . Even myself not sure what that MessageBox is since its popping up for less than a second and getting invisible immediately . I am not able to read whats there inside that MessageBox .

Comment: @Learner can you tell me what\s the scenario when you get the messagebox?

Comment: I have updated the code as you said .
This application runs at the bottom right corner of the window .
So lets say apllication is running and i opened one of my excel sheet then this excel sheet overlaps my application window . So next time when my cursor move to bottom right corner , my application works fine but one unknown MessageBox pops up and getting invisible within a fraction of second which is very irritating .Till the time no windows overlaps my application the MessageBox will not pop up .Please help me in this .Let me know if you need any more inputs from my end ..

Comment: unfortunately i don't know what's the cause for that... it seems to be outside your application.... if you have any place in your application that pops messagebox, disable that. if it is outside your application i don't know what can you do